# How does exact list comparison work?

Tags: python, list, comparison

I was making a code in which I needed to compare two lists for exact matches, and I found this code (I had to add `print` so it would output the result):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [9,8,7,6,5]
print [i for i, j in zip(a, b) if i == j]
```

This code outputs `[5]` because it prints the list, and if I change the code to

```
a = [1,2,3,5,4]
b = [9,8,7,6,5]
print [i for i, j in zip(a, b) if i == j]
```

It outputs `[]` because the list is empty.

This is all fine and good because it solves my list comparison problem, but I have almost no idea why or how it works. I would greatly appreciate either a detailed or partial explanation if you have one.

Comment: Which part of this don't you understand? Do you know how list comprehensions work? Do you know what `zip(a, b)` does? Do you know what `i == j` does? Answering all of this would be far too broad for a single Q&A.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question on this site. I don't know how _exact_ list comprehensions work, but I know how to compare lists in other ways. I also do not know what `i == j` does.

Comment: Just in case all you're asking about is the actual result of this comparison method: it returns only those elements that are the same _and_ in the same position in the two lists.

Comment: Thanks, I know what it does. I just need to know how it does it.

Comment: Hi Gabe, welcome to StackOverflow! There is a [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) with tips on how to ask good questions. You probably had no way of knowing your question would be too broad, but a quick tour of the help center will aid you in refining your questions. Cheers!

Comment: "I also do not know what i == j does." So you don't understand what it means if you write `if i == j: print i`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's called a "list comprehension", let's break it down here:

`[i for i, j in zip(a, b) if i == j]` can be roughly understood as making a list of `[i]`, where `i` (and `j`) come from `zip(a, b)` but only if `i == j`.

`zip(a, b)` takes two arrays, `a` and `b`, and combines them in such a way that the end result looks like `[(1, 9), (2, 8), ...]`

So effectively, you're processing the result of `zip(a, b)` and iterating over tuples `i, j` to return only if `i == j` is "truthy". Explaining "truthy" is a bit out of scope for this answer, but in this case, the expression `i == j` evaluates to `True` if `i` and `j` have the same value. I.e., `5 == 5` is `True`, where `5 == 4` is `False`.

Comment: He said in a comment that he doesn't understand what `i == j` means. So telling him that it returns only matches where `i == j` may not be very meaningful.

Comment: Good call, I answered before that comment. I'll update the answer with a brief explanation on that. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a list comprehension, which is a python syntax feature. [You can read about it in the python tutorial here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

It is being combined with the `zip()` built-in function. [Documentation for that function is here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

A tl;dr is: the zip function makes pairs from both lists, and the list comprehension will filter out the pairs that don't compare equal, selecting only the pairs that match

Comment: A _tl;dr_ at the end...epic

Comment: ...and then just the first element of each pair is selected.... These questions are crazy to answer, you never know how much or little the OP even knows.

Answer (score 0):

To get the code working with the random indexing of the elements, you can try the following:

a = [1,2,3,5,4]
b = [9,8,7,6,5]

print [i for i in a for j in b if i == j]

This will output:
[5]